# Wil uservoice-type questions clog up the Unanswered list?

Tags: support, meta

Seems to me that most of the uservoice-type questions (typically with status- tags) are unanswerable, or the answer is implicit in the status tag.

Doesn't this mean that in the long run the Unanswered list (and count) is going to become poluted by these questions?

(Sorry for the meta-meta question...)

Comment: I love the meta-meta

Answer (score 1):

I also observed this occurring, 
and instead visit the [MetaSO homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Generally, [as the TheTXI mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/wil-uservoice-type-questions-clog-up-the-unanswered-list/8067#8067), you or I will not have the answers to the hard-to-answer/unanswerable MetaSO questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we should always look at Meta in the same way we look at the other sites. And I imagine that the ones you claim to be "unanswerable" will end up being answered by someone like Atwood when a decision is finally made on it.

And as for the questions not having accepted answers, you can't really blame anybody by question authors for that.

Comment: I don't see what the answer to 'please fix this bug' is. The problem is that issues don't necessarily fit the question/answer/tag model. Proof of which is that issue statuses have been shoe-horned into tags. And judging from the first 50 status-completed, only a small proportion have accepted answers.

Comment: The answer is normally going to be whatever Atwood says, because his word is official. I don't know how you can get a more definitive answer than that.

Comment: Benjol: Also, like I said in my answer, you can't blame anybody but the question's original author for not accepting an answer.

Comment: Except if Jeff ONLY adds the tag but doesn't answer, which often appears to be the case...

Comment: And not just Jeff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/flair-bug-link-to-unexisting-css-file